# Is this true that $E(XY) =E(X) E(Y)$ implies the statistical independence of two normal random variables?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two normal variables and $$E(XY) = E(X) E(Y),$$ then is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

I know that when $(X,Y)$ obeys bivariate normal distribution, the statement is true. But in general, I am not sure. If this statement is wrong, then is there some easy ways to prove the independence of two normal variables?

Comment: For any 2 random variables $X,Y$, one should use the definition of independence in terms of probability rather than 'expectation' (which is implied by the former).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

Suppose $X$ is normally distributed $N(0,1)$, and $Z$ is uniformly distributed on $\{-1,+1\}$ and independent of $X$.

Set $Y=XZ$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are both normal distributed, so $E(X)E(Y)=0\cdot 0 = 0$, but $E(XY)=E(X^2Z)$ is clearly also $0$. And $X$ and $Y$ are far from independent.

Comment: Why is $Y$ normally distributed?

Comment: @AreaMan: because for all intervals $[a,b]$ we have $$P(Y\in[a,b])=\tfrac12 P(X\in[a,b])+\tfrac12 P(X\in[-b,-a]) = P(X\in[a,b])$$ where the last equals sign is because the distribution of $X$ is symmetric around $0$. So $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$, which happens to be a normal distribution.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you very much for your smart example! Do you have some time to take a look at another question of mine http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940368/are-these-two-random-variables-b-1-and-b-2-independent-of-each-other?

Comment: Kindly, I am a pragmatist, and here is the analysis after reading your profile: an immense amount of positive karma you were exercising by sharing your knowledge with us at the site was interrupted voluntarily by you in exchange for a principle stance that is unlikely to have any effect on the corporate policies of the site. You were never writing for the site. Best wishes to you.

Answer (score 3):

ok, You want normal distributions.  Suppose $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and

$$
X = \begin{cases} \phantom{-}Z & \text{if } -c<Z<c, \\  -Z & \text{if } Z>c \text{ or } Z<-c. \end{cases}
$$
If $c$ is very large then $\operatorname{cor}(Z,X)<0$ and if $c$ is very small (but positive) then $\operatorname{cor}(Z,X)<0$.  Somewhere in between you get uncorrelated variables, but they are not independent.  Showing that $X$ is normally distributed I leave as an excercise.

<s>Here's one of the simplest examples:
$$
X = \begin{cases} \phantom{-}1 \\ \phantom{-}0 & \text{each with probability } \dfrac 1 3, \\ -1 \end{cases} \quad \text{and} \quad Y =X^2.
$$
Then $\operatorname{E}(X) = 0$ and $\operatorname{E}(Y) = \dfrac 2 3$ and $\operatorname{E}(XY) = 0.$</s>

Comment: @HenningMakholm : ok, I've added another example. $\qquad$