# Are these two random variables $B_1$ and $B_2$ independent of each other?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

$\{\Phi_n\}$ are independent and identically distributed random variables distributed uniformly on $[0,2\pi]$ and 
$$B_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=1}^N \cos\Phi_n$$
$$B_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=1}^N \sin\Phi_n,$$
and I want to prove that when $N$ tends to infinity, $B_1$ and $B_2$ are independent of each other. I know this does not sound like a rigorous statement, but I don't know how to put it rigorously.

I think maybe the central limit theorem can be applied here, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Look for a way to find the distribution function of a function of a random variable, then the distribution of a sum of random variables. You have to show that the joint distribution of the random variables $B_1$ and $B_2$ is $F_{B_1,B_2}(b_1,b_2)=F_{B_1}(b_1)F_{B_2}(b_2)$.

Comment: These are just the $x$ and $y$ components, respectively, of an $N$-step random walk in two dimensions, with step size $1/\sqrt{N}$. As $N\rightarrow\infty$, this just becomes a two-dimensional Brownian motion, which necessarily has independent $x$ and $y$ components.

Comment: @Ana Do you seriously think that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are independent for each fixed $N$? Looking at the case $N=1$ could help dispel some misconceptions...

Comment: @Doris You stay remarkably silent about your background an about the approaches you tried to solve this (no, "I have been told to use CLT" does not count), so it is difficult to really help you but, anyway, the meaning of the statement you are asking about is that, when $N\to\infty$, $$(B_1^{(N)},B_2^{(N)})\to(U,V)$$ in distribution, **for some independent $U$ and $V$** (this is called asymptotic independence of $B_1^{N)}$ and $B_2^{(N)}$). To prove this, note that $E(\cos\Phi_1)=E(\sin\Phi_1)=0$ hence, by the standard CLT, $$B_1^{(N)}+iB_2^{(N)}\to U+iV$$ in distribution, ...

Comment: ... where $(U,V)$ is centered normal, hence, thanks to the nice properties of gaussian families, the desired asymptotic independence follows if you can show that $$E(UV)=0$$ that is, $$E(B_1^{(N)}B_2^{(N)})\to0$$ Now that we are back to a simple computation, can you finish this?

Comment: @Did, I don't understand the part "thanks to the nice properties of gaussian families, the desired asymptotic independence follows if you can show that", do you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: You first: what does the words "the nice properties of gaussian families" refer to, according to you?

Comment: @Did, Thanks a lot! I found [the multidimensional central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Multidimensional_CLT) and it all makes sense now.

Comment: @Did Sorry, I was in a hurry and I totally forgot to say that he has to show that my last expression holds in the limit $N\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** I can summon very little intuition about this problem. So I
tried a straightforward simulation in R statistical software.

From a simulation of 100,000
iterations, each with n = 20, one can see that the sample correlation of
$B_1$ and $B_2$ is consistent with 0 population correlation. Furthermore, no
association is evident in the scatterplot.

```
m = 10^5;  n = 20
phi = runif(m*n, 0, 2*pi)
PHI = matrix(phi, nrow=m)
A.1 = rowSums(sin(PHI))
A.2 = rowSums(cos(PHI))
B.1 = A.1/sqrt(n); B.2 = A.2/sqrt(n)
cor(B.1, B.2)
## -0.00383627
```

[image]

*Note:* This is a corrected post. The original had typos in the R code.
I regret any inconvenience from posting garbage for an hour.

Comment: The plot fits well a pair of independent centered gaussian random variables, for good reasons (see my comments on main). Not sure I am able to estimate the variance $\frac12$ in each direction just by looking at the plot, though... :-)